# High CPU usage and application is lagging

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to troubleshoot a issue in the customer site.
This application mainly is fetching some data from the DB , and reading some registry settings.

But this exe is using almost 13% of CPU ( total 32GB RAM ) and causing the latency like it is taking almost ~3 mins to send the response { In other sites it completes within seconds with same amount of data in the DB , and CPU usage is very less }
But this is happening in only one customer site , all the other sites which are having the same version is not having any issues .

I got the trace from process explorer looks like "mscorlib" is taking time while it is reading the registry.

```
AcLayers.DLL!NotifyShims+0x19fb
AcLayers.DLL!NotifyShims+0x22df
AcLayers.DLL!NotifyShims+0x12df7
AcLayers.DLL!NotifyShims+0xe92
[Native Frame: IL Method without Metadata]
[Managed to Unmanaged Transition]
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll!Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey+0x8f
C:\Program Files\...\xxxxx.EXE!xx.modMLAcommon.GetRegistrySetting+0xf5
C:\Program Files\...\xxxxx.EXE!xxx.modMLAcommon.IsDiagnosticMode+0x47
C:\Program Files\...\xxxxx.EXE!xxx.ReplaceXMLtag+0x54c
```

What could cause the delay while reading the registry ? That too only in one site , because there are many other sites which has the same exe and still it is reading quickly.

My question might be bit vague , because all other possible things i tried and compared like the .NET version , windows pathes .
And i also confirmed the this delay is not beacuse of no of records in DB ,
from the call stack it is pretty much clear that every time it is taking time while reading the registry.

Framework for EXE : .NET 4.7.1

Language : VB.NET

Class used for reading the registry : RegistryKey (Namespace Microsoft.Win32)

mscorlib dll version : 4.7.3946.0

Comment: Please don't tag this post C# if your software is VB.Net. In addition, it's hard to debug problems with your code if you can't produce a [mre].

Comment: Its something that is different between the environments. Its very hard to play spot the difference when you can't see either side.

Comment: Yep it cleary looks like site specific causing due to environments , but compared almost every things , so that is surprising me

Comment: Does the problem site use anti-malware software that is different from all the other sites?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes they were using crowdstrike , but we asked them to remove , as of now they dont have any third party software , in the control panel i can see only microsoft software and our company related softwares

Comment: 1) Does the program use the registry for its own data, or is it reading information about Windows? If the former, then you should see [Performance of reading a registry key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3929717/1115360) and consider changing to different storage. 2) A wild guess, but do the problem computers happen to use HDDs instead of SSDs, and are they in desperate need of being defragmented?

Comment: @AndrewMorton For 1) We are reading our own data
for 2 ) Problem computers using HDD and when i saw other site it is using Thin Provisioned drive or SSD { Thanks for this hint } will it cause delay ?

Comment: @NitheeshKedlaya I suggest that you try storing your data somewhere other than in the registry. You will probably need to write some code to transfer the existing data from the registry the first time the new version of the program is installed.